# Upload images API on 3rd Party host .. Flickr?

Tags: image, api, upload, share, host

I am building an Image Sharing feature for my website, where users can upload images and show it off on my website, through their own profile gallery. Except I dont want to physically host  the uploaded images.

Are there API's that can allow me to descretly save the uploaded images (from the users) to another Host, such as Flickr, Google etc..

I know Flickr has a good API, but could I use it for this? And does the Flickr Upload API only work with authorised users ? becuase I dont want them to upload to their Flickr account, but just host them with 1 big account so to speak

thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. I found http://uploads.im/ website which seems free. Interesting of someone has experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Amazon S3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/), also [Imgur](http://imgur.com) has an [API](http://code.google.com/p/imgur-api/)

Comment: hmm amazon seems way too hard to use .. and imgur api isnt free for commercial use